# How do I determine the size of each of the heap generations in my JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

If I start my JVM with -Xms256M and -Xmx512M, at any point of time, can I determine the amount of space specifically allocated to the young and tenured generations of the heap ?

Comment: http://www.java-examples.com/get-maximum-memory-available-java-virtual-machinejvm-example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm presuming you mean determining this *programmatically*. You should take a peek at [`java.lang.management`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/package-summary.html). In particular, [`ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html#getMemoryPoolMXBeans()) should be useful here.

```
final List<MemoryPoolMXBeans> pools = ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans();
for (final MemoryPoolMXBean pool : pools) {
  if (pool.getType() == MemoryType.HEAP) {
    final String name = pool.getName();
    final MemoryUsage usage = pool.getUsage();
    if (name.startsWith("Eden")) {
      System.out.println("found eden: " + usage);
    } else if (name.startsWith("Tenured")) {
      System.out.println("found tenured: " + usage);
    }
  }
}
```

This should work using the HotSpot JVM.

If you're **not** seeking to do this programmatically, [VisualVM](https://web.archive.org/web/20170729032925/http://visualvm.java.net:80/) (`jvisualvm` in the JDK) allows you to monitor heap usage amongst many other nifty things.

[image]
<sub>(source: [java.net](https://visualvm.java.net/images/monitor.jpg))</sub>

Note, however, that VisualVM lacks support of monitoring specific memory pools out-of-the-box; you'll need to install [jvmstat](https://web.archive.org/web/20120719044644/http://java.sun.com:80/performance/jvmstat/). You must then install the **Visual GC** plugin from VisualVM's plugin manager.

http://puu.sh/YCpX

After installing and restarting Visual VM, we can see a more in-depth view of heap usage via the Visual GC tab.

http://puu.sh/YCqD

Answer (score 2):

Use [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) to easily monitor the heap sizes. You can see different gen sizes in the memory tab. Select the gen you want from the Chart drop down.